# Icon flipping in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

According to [Kendo's docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/icons-web#flipping), it should be possible to flip a button's icon using a CSS class (`k-flip-h` to flip horizontally, and `k-flip-v` to flip vertically).

I am doing this just like the docs using a span:

```js
$("#normal").kendoButton();
$("#flipped").kendoButton();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">
    <button id="normal">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-pencil"/>
    </button>
    <button id="flipped">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-pencil k-flip-h"/>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This yields two buttons that look identical. The second button *should* be flipped but isn't.

I suppose this makes sense, because doing a [full-text search in their Github repo for "k-flip-h"](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=k-flip-h&type=) doesn't find the "k-flip-h" text anywhere except the docs. It is nowhere to be found in their Javascript or CSS.

Does this feature actually exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be missing.  You can add the following CSS (borrowed from font awesome) to make it work:

```
.k-flip-h {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0, mirror=1)";
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.k-flip-v {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1)";
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/acotA)**